# Looping through 3 different SQL results

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, loops

I need to loop through 3 results of SQL queries. The problem is that it's only bringing the fist result, instead of all of them.

```
exports.rewardsNotifications = function() {
    var now = new Date()
    var hourUTC = now.getUTCHours()

    if (hourUTC <= 18) {
        db.task(t => {
            return t.any(`SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.phone_number, customer.place_group_id, customer.state, MAX(visit_date_only) AS last_visit, COUNT(visit_date) AS visit_count FROM VISITS
            INNER JOIN customer ON visits.customer_id = customer.customer_id AND visits.place_group_id = customer.place_group_id
            WHERE customer.state = 'on' GROUP BY customer.customer_id`).then(function(visitsData) {

                for(var i=0; i<visitsData.length; i++){
                    var customer_id = visitsData[i]['customer_id']
                    var phone_number = visitsData[i]['phone_number']
                    var place_group_id_visits = visitsData[i]['place_group_id']
                    var last_visit = visitsData[i]['last_visit']
                    var visit_count = visitsData[i]['visit_count']


                return t.any(`SELECT rewards_list.reward_name, rewards_list.required_visits, rewards_list.place_group_id FROM rewards_list`).then(function(rewards){

                    for(var j=0; j<rewards.length; j++){
                        var reward_name = rewards[j]['reward_name']
                        var reward_required_visits = rewards[j]['required_visits']
                        var place_group_id_rewards = rewards[j]['place_group_id']


                    return t.any(`SELECT customer_id, reward_name, place_group_id FROM rewards`).then(function(redeemedRewards){

                        for(var k=0; k<redeemedRewards.length; k++){
                            var redeemed_reward_customer_id = redeemedRewards[k]['customer_id']
                            var reward_redeemed_name = redeemedRewards[k]['reward_name']
                            var reward_rest_group_id = redeemedRewards[k]['place_group_id']


                        console.log('THIS ARE THE REWARDS', reward_name)
                        console.log('THIS IS THE CUSTOMERS', customer_id)

                    }
                    })

                }
                })

                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

On my console.log, I'm just getting the first result from the queries (not all customers, not all rewards).
What I want to do is check (for all customers) what rewards a customer has redeemed and which they haven't.

Comment: You should be able to just write SQL query that will get you those results and not need to do looping or anything like that in javascript to figure that out

Comment: Can you please specify the connection string used? (make sure you strip away any sensitive info)